# Django giving error when trying to get path to static file

Tags: django, static-files, xhtml2pdf

I'm trying to implement xhtml2pdf, and in my html file, it references a static file.  I have the file in my project at `jobs/static/jobs/style.css`.  When using the code xhtml2pdf provides in their docs, I am getting an error when it gets to `result = finders.find(uri)`  saying `django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path (/static/jobs/css/style.css) is located outside of the base path component (/opt/project/myproject/static)`.  If I navigate to the url that the file should be at, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/jobs/css/style.css`, I see the code of the css file, so it is in the generally correct location.

This project is being served in a docker container, and there is nothing stored in /opt, so I don't know why it coming up with this "base path component" at (/opt/project/myproject/static).  I don't know where it is getting this path.  I have searched my entire project, and there is no path, in any file, that includes `opt` or `project`.  The project is stored in /app in the container.

Here is the code I got from their site:

```
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
import os
import io
from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders


def link_callback(uri, rel):
    """
    Convert HTML URIs to absolute system paths so xhtml2pdf can access those
    resources
    """
    result = finders.find(uri)
    if result:
        if not isinstance(result, (list, tuple)):
            result = [result]
        result = list(os.path.realpath(path) for path in result)
        path = result[0]
    else:
        sUrl = settings.STATIC_URL  # Typically /static/
        sRoot = settings.STATIC_ROOT  # Typically /home/userX/project_static/
        mUrl = settings.MEDIA_URL  # Typically /media/
        mRoot = settings.MEDIA_ROOT  # Typically /home/userX/project_static/media/

        if uri.startswith(mUrl):
            path = os.path.join(mRoot, uri.replace(mUrl, ""))
        elif uri.startswith(sUrl):
            path = os.path.join(sRoot, uri.replace(sUrl, ""))
        else:
            return uri

    # make sure that file exists
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
        raise Exception(
            'media URI must start with %s or %s' % (sUrl, mUrl)
        )
    return path


def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict, bytes=False):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    context = context_dict
    if bytes:
        response = io.BytesIO()
    else:
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="contract.pdf"'
    html = template.render(context)

    pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(html, dest=response, link_callback=link_callback)

    # if error then show some funny view
    if pisa_status.err:
        return HttpResponse('We had some errors <pre>' + html + '</pre>')
    return response
```

Here is the relevant portion of my settings.py:

```
ROOT_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent.parent  # Resolves to /app
APPS_DIR = ROOT_DIR / "myproject"  # Resolves to /app/myproject

STATIC_ROOT = str(ROOT_DIR / "staticfiles")  # Resolves to /app/staticfiles
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    str(APPS_DIR / "static"),
    str(ROOT_DIR / "node_modules"),
]  # Resolves to ['/app/myproject/static', '/app/node_modules']
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]

MEDIA_ROOT = str(APPS_DIR / "media")  # Resolves to /app/media/myproject/media
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

The line I have in my html template that is being the problem is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'jobs/css/style.css' %}">
```

I have another project I have been using this in for about a year, using this same code, and it has been working without this error.  The other project is not inside a docker container, but I don't see why that should make a difference.

Where else should I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When integrating `xhtml2pdf` with Django, especially within Docker, you might encounter file path issues due to the way Django handles static files. The `SuspiciousFileOperation` error typically arises when a path is evaluated as being outside the expected base directory.

Here's a consolidated solution, breaking down the possible causes and providing the recommended fixes:

1. **Static Files Handling**:

   `xhtml2pdf` requires absolute system paths to access static and media resources. When running in a Docker container, the file paths inside the container might differ from those on the host machine. Ensure your static settings are properly set up to reflect the paths within the Docker container.
2. **Enhance the `link_callback` Function**:

   Modify the `link_callback` function to cater to both absolute and relative paths. The function should ideally:

   - Convert relative URLs to absolute system paths.
   - Verify that the constructed path exists on the filesystem.

   Here's an optimized `link_callback` function using settings approach:

   ```py
   import os
   from django.conf import settings

   def link_callback(uri, rel):
       if uri.startswith(settings.MEDIA_URL):
           path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.MEDIA_URL, ""))
       elif uri.startswith(settings.STATIC_URL):
           path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.STATIC_URL, ""))
       else:
           return uri

       # Ensure the file exists
       if not os.path.isfile(path):
           raise Exception(f"Path does not exist: {path}")

       return path
   ```

   If you're using `finders`, you're trying to get the actual path of the file based on its URL. The problem might arise if the path returned is not what you expect due to different folder structures or volume mappings inside the Docker container.

   ```py
   from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders

   path = finders.find(uri)
   ```

   Given your current scenario and the `SuspiciousFileOperation` error you're facing, I recommend sticking to the `settings` approach. It's more straightforward and makes fewer assumptions about your project's structure.

   However, if you prefer to use `finders`, ensure you understand how it's resolving paths and make sure the resolved paths align with the actual file structure inside your Docker container.
3. **Docker Volume Mapping**:

   Ensure that the volume mapping between your host machine and Docker container is correctly configured. Double-check the Docker Compose or Docker command to verify that the application directory (`/app` in your case) is accurately mapped.
4. **Collect Static Files**:

   If `DEBUG` is set to `False` in Django settings, make sure to run `collectstatic` to gather all static files in the `STATIC_ROOT` location:

   ```bash
   python manage.py collectstatic
   ```

   This step ensures that all static files are available in the designated `STATIC_ROOT` directory, allowing `xhtml2pdf` to access them.
5. **File Permissions**:

   Sometimes, it might be a permission issue. Ensure that the user running the Django application inside the Docker container has the necessary permissions to access and read the static and media files.

By combining these recommendations, you should be able to successfully generate PDFs with `xhtml2pdf` in your Django project running inside a Docker container.

Comment: Okay, in my testing, I assumed ROOT_DIR resolved to where it said it resolved to when I was running the manage.py shell, which resolves to /app/myproject.  As far as my compose file, and where I find things with a bash shell, things should be stored in /app, but they resolve to `/opt/project` while running.  Needless to say, this works, but only if I run `collectstatic` first, and this is even when `debug=True`, since this bypasses the finders.